# Iterate rows of a data frame and create a new data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

**Goal:**
I want to create one data frame per NFL game week looking like this:

```
Week 1
Home                       Away
Arizona Cardinals          Tennessee Titans
Los Angeles Chargers       Washington Football Team
.
.
.

Week 2
Home                       Away
.
.
.
```

**What do I have:**
a data frame of the schedule as grid:

```
print(df_sched)
0   Week      Arizona Cardinals           Atlanta Falcons      Baltimore Ravens  ...    San Francisco 49ers       Tampa Bay Buccaneers       Tennessee Titans Washington Football Team
1      1      @Tennessee Titans       Philadelphia Eagles    @Las Vegas Raiders  ...         @Detroit Lions             Dallas Cowboys      Arizona Cardinals     Los Angeles Chargers
2      2      Minnesota Vikings     @Tampa Bay Buccaneers    Kansas City Chiefs  ...   @Philadelphia Eagles            Atlanta Falcons      @Seattle Seahawks          New York Giants
3      3  @Jacksonville Jaguars          @New York Giants        @Detroit Lions  ...      Green Bay Packers          @Los Angeles Rams     Indianapolis Colts           @Buffalo Bills
4      4      @Los Angeles Rams  Washington Football Team       @Denver Broncos  ...       Seattle Seahawks      @New England Patriots         @New York Jets         @Atlanta Falcons
```

**Proposed solution:**

1. I would create an empty df_temp=['Away', 'Home'] and start filling
   it using iterrows.
2. Based on if there is an '@' in the row value,
   the team in the row is the 'Home'-Team, else the team in the column
   header is the 'Home'-Team.
3. The result should be one df per game week
   (df_week1, df_week2, ..., df_week18)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


cols = ['Week','Arizona Cardinals','Atlanta Falcons','Baltimore Ravens',
        'San Francisco 49ers','Tampa Bay Buccaneers','Tennessee Titans',
        'Washington Football Team']

data = [[1,'@Tennessee Titans','Philadelphia Eagles','@Las Vegas Raiders','@Detroit Lions','Dallas Cowboys','Arizona Cardinals','Los Angeles Chargers'],
      [2,'Minnesota Vikings','@Tampa Bay Buccaneers','Kansas City Chiefs','@Philadelphia Eagles','Atlanta Falcons','@Seattle Seahawks','New York Giants'],
      [3,'@Jacksonville Jaguars ','@New York Giants','@Detroit Lions','Green Bay Packers','@Los Angeles Rams','Indianapolis Colts','@Buffalo Bills'],
      [4, '@Los Angeles Rams','Washington Football Team','@Denver Broncos','Seattle Seahawks','@New England Patriots','@New York Jets','@Atlanta Falcons']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)


dfs = {}
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    rows = []
    for alpha, beta in row.iteritems():
        if alpha == 'Week':
            df_name = 'df_week%.2d' %beta
        else:
            if '@' in beta:
                awayTeam = alpha
                homeTeam = beta.replace('@','')
            else:
                awayTeam = beta
                homeTeam = alpha
                
            row = {'Home':homeTeam, 'Away':awayTeam}
            rows.append(row)
            
    dfs[df_name] = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
for k, v in dfs.items():
    print(k, '\n',  v, '\n')

df_week01 
                        Home                  Away
0          Tennessee Titans     Arizona Cardinals
1           Atlanta Falcons   Philadelphia Eagles
2         Las Vegas Raiders      Baltimore Ravens
3             Detroit Lions   San Francisco 49ers
4      Tampa Bay Buccaneers        Dallas Cowboys
5          Tennessee Titans     Arizona Cardinals
6  Washington Football Team  Los Angeles Chargers 

df_week02 
                        Home                 Away
0         Arizona Cardinals    Minnesota Vikings
1      Tampa Bay Buccaneers      Atlanta Falcons
2          Baltimore Ravens   Kansas City Chiefs
3       Philadelphia Eagles  San Francisco 49ers
4      Tampa Bay Buccaneers      Atlanta Falcons
5          Seattle Seahawks     Tennessee Titans
6  Washington Football Team      New York Giants 

df_week03 
                     Home                      Away
0  Jacksonville Jaguars          Arizona Cardinals
1        New York Giants           Atlanta Falcons
2          Detroit Lions          Baltimore Ravens
3    San Francisco 49ers         Green Bay Packers
4       Los Angeles Rams      Tampa Bay Buccaneers
5       Tennessee Titans        Indianapolis Colts
6          Buffalo Bills  Washington Football Team 

df_week04 
                    Home                      Away
0      Los Angeles Rams         Arizona Cardinals
1       Atlanta Falcons  Washington Football Team
2        Denver Broncos          Baltimore Ravens
3   San Francisco 49ers          Seattle Seahawks
4  New England Patriots      Tampa Bay Buccaneers
5         New York Jets          Tennessee Titans
6       Atlanta Falcons  Washington Football Team
```